# use of -iS -p command line parameters in gradle

Tags: gradle

Gradle allows your to pass `-iS -p` as a command line parameters. what is the use of `-iS -p` command line parameters in gradle? what additional functionality they enable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checking those switches with the Gradle command's help:

```
$ gradle --help | egrep -e '^-(i|S|p)'
-i, --info              Set log level to info.
-p, --project-dir       Specifies the start directory for Gradle. Defaults to current directory.
-S, --full-stacktrace   Print out the full (very verbose) stacktrace for all exceptions.
```

`-iS` = set log level to info and print full stacktraces for exceptions

`-p` = specify the project directory